# Spring use different property files depending on request params

Tags: java, spring, properties

**Background:**

I am working on a java Spring REST microservice that needs to work with multiple identical back-end systems and multiple identical databases depending on the request parameters.

Basically I have 3 "brands". For each brand there is a set of downstream services and a database. I have no control over those.

My spring service will receive brand as a part of request and will need to call the right downstream services and use the correct database.

Previously I would deal with this by having a separate instance of the spring service for each of the brands. There would be a single property file for each brand and spring would use it to wire up beans. I would have separate URL's for each brand and there was no problem.

Some of my beans need to know about "brand" during creation as they are wrappers around connections downstream services. I.e. once the bean is created there won't be a way to switch it to be a "different brand".

**Problem:**

I would like to change this so that a single instance of my service can handle requests for any brand.

**Requirements:**
I was thinking about the following solution:

Have a general property file for non-branded stuff. Spring would wire any non-branded beans and keep them as singleton beans.

Have a property file with brand specific urls etc for each of the brands
Spring would create set of singleton beans for each of the brand using appropriate property file.

Next when the request comes in spring would read the request params and use bean specific for that brand.

Performance is important to me so I would like to reuse the beans as much as possible.

I would like to make this thing as transparent as possible so that people creating new beans don't have to worry about doing anything outside standard configuration/context class.

Does anyone know what would be the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve the problem injecting the service in every request with the right set of configurations and beans; possibly already existing in your Application Context.

Given:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/greetings/rodo && echo
Hi from brand1, rodo
$ curl -H "x-brand-name: brand1" http://localhost:8080/greetings/rodo
Hi from brand1, rodo
$ curl -H "x-brand-name: brand2" http://localhost:8080/greetings/rodo && echo
Hi from brand2, rodo
```

The following code would work:

**-- application.yml --**

```
brand1:
  greetingPrefix: Hi from brand1,

brand2:
  greetingPrefix: Hi from brand2,
```

**-- DemoApplication.java --**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    class ServiceConfig {
        @Bean
        public GreetingService greetingServiceBrand1(Brand1Config config) {
            return new GreetingService(config);
        }

        @Bean
        public GreetingService greetingServiceBrand2(Brand2Config config) {
            return new GreetingService(config);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
            resolvers.add(greetingServiceResolver());
        }

        private GreetingServiceResolver greetingServiceResolver() {
            GreetingService greetingServiceBrand1 = applicationContext.getBean("greetingServiceBrand1", GreetingService.class);
            GreetingService greetingServiceBrand2 = applicationContext.getBean("greetingServiceBrand2", GreetingService.class);
            return new GreetingServiceResolver(greetingServiceBrand1, greetingServiceBrand2);
        }
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greetings")
class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public String get(GreetingService greetingService, @PathVariable String name) {
        return greetingService.sayHi(name);
    }
}

class GreetingServiceResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    private final GreetingService greetingServiceBrand1;
    private final GreetingService greetingServiceBrand2;

    public GreetingServiceResolver(GreetingService greetingServiceBrand1, GreetingService greetingServiceBrand2) {
        this.greetingServiceBrand1 = greetingServiceBrand1;
        this.greetingServiceBrand2 = greetingServiceBrand2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(GreetingService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(
            MethodParameter methodParameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
            NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory
    ) throws Exception {
        String brand = nativeWebRequest.getHeader("x-brand-name");
        return resolveGreetingService(brand);
    }

    private GreetingService resolveGreetingService(String brand) {
        if ("brand2".equals(brand)) {
            return greetingServiceBrand2;
        }
        return greetingServiceBrand1; // default
    }
}

class GreetingService {
    private BaseConfig config;

    public GreetingService(BaseConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public String sayHi(String name) {
        return config.getGreetingPrefix() + " " + name;
    }
}

abstract class BaseConfig {
    private String greetingPrefix;

    public String getGreetingPrefix() {
        return greetingPrefix;
    }

    public void setGreetingPrefix(String greetingPrefix) {
        this.greetingPrefix = greetingPrefix;
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("brand1")
class Brand1Config extends BaseConfig {
}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("brand2")
class Brand2Config extends BaseConfig {
}
```

As you can see, it's fundamental to pass the service to each controller method, write a resolver and inject the right set of dependencies depending on a parameter passed to the request, in this case via header.

Answer (score 0):

Since your property files need to be declared statically anyway, you can just write all your different brand stuff in the same property file, like in a key-value format, that Spring can pick up as a list of configurations.

```
brandConfigs:
 - brand: foo
   property: foos
 - brand2: bar
   porperty: bars
```

Load all your connection beans to your downstream services on startup and just route to them according to your request param. Imo this seems to be the most straight forward and performant way. If some of these downstreams are used very rarely you can lazy load the beans on-demand, but probably this wouldn't make a sense unless you have thousands of different downstream routes.